# jQuery display image title in span tag

Tags: jquery, append, title

I have a unordered list being shown - each li tag contains an image with an empty span tag under it. I want the title attribute of the image to display in the span tag. I am using this below and it works, but it shows the titles from ALL images in the first span tag...  I need to somehow make sure the title from the image goes in its own span tag. I guess I need a way to have a unique ID for each li or each li img...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pressThumbs li img').fadeIn(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $("#description").append($(this).attr('title'));
    });
});
```

Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 3):

IDs must be unique. As such, you can only have *one* `description` id on the page.

Change the ID `description` to a class instead, and do this:

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/gsFnW/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pressThumbs li img').fadeIn(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.next('.description').append($this.attr('title'));
    });
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/next/

Please note that this assumes the `<img>` and the `<span>` are next to each other. I can't say for sure without seeing your markup. If there's another element in between, do this instead.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pressThumbs li img').fadeIn(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.siblings('.description').append($this.attr('title'));
    });
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: i have done modification to show title only on hover [http://jsfiddle.net/gsFnW/48/](http://jsfiddle.net/gsFnW/48/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this markup

```
<ul>
   <li><img src="bla" title="sometitle" /><span class="description" /></li>
   <li><img src="bla" title="sometitle" /><span class="description" /></li>
</ul>
```

This should work.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
 { 
     $('#pressThumbs li img').fadeIn(function() 
     { 
          var $this = $(this); 
          $this.siblings(".description").html($this.attr('title')); 
     }); 
 });
```

You're problem is that you are using an id attribute #decription which can only appear on a single dom item. Instead use a class which can appear and many.

Hope this helps.